# FindFit cannot give me the right result. What should I do?

Tags: fitting

```
T101msx = {-0.1, -0.7, -3.4, -0.7, -0.9, 5.5, 3.7, 2.6, 3.9, 3.5, 3.5,
6.7, 12, 21.1, 29.7, 39.5, 52.8, 67.7, 78.9, 95, 109.1, 123.7, 
139.6, 152.7, 163.9, 172, 181.5, 186.7, 192.8, 195.8, 192.4, 188.4, 
182.4, 167.3, 150.8, 136.9, 119.6, 105.3, 88.2, 71.2, 59.1, 44.6, 
30.5, 24.1, 15.8, 10.9, 7.8, 5.2, 3.7, 5.3, 4.3, 3.3, 1, 
0.6, -1.4, -3.3}
gp = ListPlot[T101msx]
eqn[x_] := 1/(Sqrt[2 Pi]*a)*Exp[-(x - b)^2/(2 a^2)]
FindFit[T101msx, eqn[x], {{a, 10}, {b, 30}}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]

Out[53]:{a -> 0.00197028, b -> 30.0005}

Show[Show[ListPlot[T101msx, PlotStyle -> Red], 
Plot[eqn[x] /. {a -> 0.0019702769777831825`, b -> 30.000510344955828`}, {x, 1, 56}]]]
```

The parameters given by `FindFit` is obviously incorrect. Although I give parameter 'a' a initial value 10. What should I do? (Ignore those Chinese comments) Thank u.
[image]

Comment: You should post your actual code instead of an image

Comment: For whatever it's worth, my answer and @PratyayGhosh 's answer give identical predictions.  Our models are equivalent but just parameterize the model differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mathematica* is doing fine with the model you gave it.  The problem is your model.  You don't have a probability distribution being estimated from a random sample.  You have a regression where you want to fit the same shape as a Gaussian curve - but multiplied by an appropriate constant so you need one more parameter.

```
T101msx = {-0.1, -0.7, -3.4, -0.7, -0.9, 5.5, 3.7, 2.6, 3.9, 3.5, 3.5,
   6.7, 12, 21.1, 29.7, 39.5, 52.8, 67.7, 78.9, 95, 109.1, 123.7, 
  139.6, 152.7, 163.9, 172, 181.5, 186.7, 192.8, 195.8, 192.4, 188.4, 
  182.4, 167.3, 150.8, 136.9, 119.6, 105.3, 88.2, 71.2, 59.1, 44.6, 
  30.5, 24.1, 15.8, 10.9, 7.8, 5.2, 3.7, 5.3, 4.3, 3.3, 1, 
  0.6, -1.4, -3.3}
eqn[x_] := a*Exp[-(x - b)^2/(2 c^2)]
sol = FindFit[T101msx, eqn[x], {{a, 200}, {b, 30}, {c, 10}}, x, 
  Method -> "NMinimize"]
(* {a -> 197.404, b -> 29.3913, c -> 7.46827} *)

Show[ListPlot[T101msx, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[eqn[x] /. sol, {x, 1, 56}]]
```

[image: Fit to Gaussian shape]

Answer (score 1):

The Fit you are getting is absolutely correct. What I understand is you are trying to fit the data with a Normal distribution. In that case, your $a$ should be around $1/(198.5 \sqrt{2\pi})$ and $b$ should be close to $30$. You got it both correct.

However, the blue plot does not match the red plot because it is the 'wrong' function. The function you used is a probability distribution function and hence, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}eqn[x]dx=1$, But this is not true for your data. Just to clarify, due to the nature of your data, the parameter $a$ becomes very small. In computation, when you take a Normal distribution and make your $a$ very small you end up getting a Dirac Delta function. That's what you are getting here.

Try doing a normalization (as normal distribution is a probability distribution), that might help.

```
    data = T101msx/Total[T101msx]
    eqn[x_] := 1/(Sqrt[2 Pi]*a)*Exp[-(x - b)^2/(2 a^2)]
    sol = FindFit[data, eqn[x], {{a, 200}, {b, 30}}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]

    Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
    Plot[eqn[x] /. sol, {x, 1, 56}]]
```

[image]

Comment: JimB, sorry I do not have enough reputation to comment. I agree with you. I might be wrong in calling it a Precision error. What I understand is this is how we create a Dirac Delta function distribution. So the function should be zero (or very very small) away from $x=b$. That's what is happening here.

Comment: I edited my answer. Jim pointed out the fact that it is the 'wrong' function. I agree.

Comment: +1 The Dirac Delta result is a good observation.  (Not scaling "probability distributions" when doing regressions is not an uncommon issue at this site.)